# Customized hyperlinks for markdown-bibtex to html conversion using Pandoc

Tags: html, pandoc, bibtex, biblatex, csl

I am using the following style to have my bibilography imported from a bibtex file in markdown and from there to html/pdf:

```
 ---
 bibliography: test.bib
 nocite: '@*'
 ...

 # Biliography
```

After that I run:

```
pandoc test.md -o test.html --bibligraphy test.bib --csl=test.csl
```

However currently the urls of bib entries after conversion to html appear  as:

```
 <a href="www.test.com/test.pdf">www.test.com/test.pdf</a>
```

I could not figure out how to change this to something like:

```
 <a href="www.test.com/test.pdf">test file!</a>
```

I could manipulate prefix and suffic by touching the csl file but could not change the hyperlink name. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the answer to this is that it's not possible. CSL just doesn't allow you to set a hyperlink on a string and since CSL is what pandoc relies on for bibliographies, there's no way to do this.